# Loading UITable data only if datasource is live from web host

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I'm a little stuck, I have a UIViewController with imageView, label button and below a UITAbleView like below

[image: Storyboard View Controller]

The table view is loaded using by parsing a website for data which works fine when the site is live, but It's not alway live. So when it's not online loading the view controller from the pushing VC takes ages and shows an empty table, I don't mind the table being empty as it's not critical to the view but the app seems frozen whilst trying to load and parse the offline site. So my question would be how is the best way to approach this issue or how to make the table view load the data after the view is loaded as the previous view controller won't push until the view is loaded of it's decided it can't parse the site.

I've tried Reachability in the VC's viewed load:
Filling the tableview arrays in viewDidAppear & reloadTableview
and many others, they all seem to have undesired effects

Thanks for taking the time to read, my ramblings.

Comment: The standard approach to avoiding a freeze is to use a background thread to get server data and switch to the main thread to update the UI after the fetch/parse is finished.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been out Obj-C for a while and I guess it shows :)

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy nowadays - have a look at 3rd party libraries like AFNetworking or Alamofire, but it can even be done simply with the standard `NSURLSession`. Here's a relevant code sample from one of my projects:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:components.URL completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error)
    {
        // Handle the error
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
        if (jsonError)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }
        else
        {
            // Here you can do whatever you want with the parsed data, and reload the tableview (remember, on the main thread)
        }
    }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```